# Display html page before document ready

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have some ajax calls in document ready to populate a table. Unfortunately the page is only being displayed once the table has been populated.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // alert('Why');
    var jsondata2a;
    turl = "/rims/tab1/get_data?abc=123";
    $.ajax({
    url: turl+"",
    cache: false,
    async: false,
    success: function(data){
            jsondata2a = data;
    },
    error: function(){
            $("#gerror").html("<p>An error has occurred!</p>");
        }
    });
```

However, if I put an alert statement in the ready function, the page displays immediately with the alert and then populates the table after accepting the alert.

The full page displays on the alert statement, but the page does not display until all the ajax calls have been completed if the alert is not there. I have tried to move the ready function to different parts of the page without success. I have tried with IE and Chrome.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Does you $.ajax() call have async set to false ?

Comment: Yes it does. I will try with true.

Comment: Tried with true. Page displays immediately, but table is never populated.

Comment: Check your ajax call in FireBug.  You should also post your entire ajax() call, maybe your ajax() is dependent on something that is not available when the call is made to the server.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. As I have posted below, wrapping all the code inside the ready function with setTimeout works well.---        $.ajax({
            url: turl+"",
            cache: false,
            async: flase,
            success: function(data){
                jsondata2a = data;
            },
            error: function(){
                $("#gerror").html("<p>An error has occurred!</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>Please go back and try again!</p>");
            }
        });

Comment: The data was not being populated with false because of my stupidity. Thank you all for the reality check. Everything understood and working the way it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. I'm sure you have other prt of scipt which know how to draw that table. just add that code in success callback

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // alert('Why');
    var jsondata2a;
    turl = "/rims/tab1/get_data?abc=123";
    $.ajax({
    url: turl+"",
    cache: false,
    // async: false,
    success: function(data){
            jsondata2a = data;
            for(var i=0; i< data.length; i++){
               $("#table_id").append("<tr>" ...boud data here data[i].someAttribute... "</tr>");
            }
    },
    error: function(){
            $("#gerror").html("<p>An error has occurred!</p>");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response Milan. That worked. Would be good to understand why.

Comment: If I could see other ajax parameter I could tell, maybe it is synchronous call so it blocks execution of other synchronous events in document... can you update your question?

Comment: just remove `async: false,` it blocks executions of other stuff in document. And you need populate table in success callback. That is what you are missing.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to wait for `$(document).ready()` to perform an ajax request. You only need to wait before interacting with the dom. As such, perform your request outside of the ready function, and listen for dom ready within your success callback.

This will not prevent your page from rendering.

```
$.ajax({
  ...
  success: function() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
      /* manipulate DOM here */
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prevent blocking with your [jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call, you must have async set to true (default).

```
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'YourURLHere.html',
            data: '{}',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            async: true,
            success: function (data, text) {
                // Do Something
            },
            error:function (request, status, error){
                // Alert Somebody
            } 
        });
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I will experiment and see if I can solve the issue. As I have posted above, setting "async: true" displays the page, but the table is never populated.